# Conditional window split

Tags: neovim, vim-windows

I have line to split window at start:

```
au VimEnter * vsplit
```

But sometimes it's annoying because I'm opening vim in small terminal, in this case I'd like to not split my window. I've tried this construction but it's not executing at start

```
if winwidth('%') >= 100
  au VimEnter * vsplit
endif
```

Is there a way to execute spit window depending on window size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try moving the `if` into the autocommand:

```
au VimEnter * if winwidth('%') >= 100 | vsplit | endif
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to check the 'winwidth' result at the time the hook is run, not when it's defined.  You can do this by putting it in a new function and calling that from the hook:

```
function Widevsplit()
  if winwidth('%') >= 100
    vsplit
  endif
endfunction

au VimEnter * call Widevsplit()
```